# Create Random Points for multiple features with varying points needed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, random

I am looking for a way to randomly create points features within all National Park forest boundaries. Each boundary has a certain number of points

Example below

PARK    Count
ABLI    60    (I would need 60 randomly generated points for this)
ACAD    413   (413 randomly generated points for this...etc)
ADAM    12
AFBG    2
AGFO    62
ALFL    19

I'd like for all of this to end up in a single shapefile

I know I can use [Create Random Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm) to do this for a single feature (aka 60 points for ABLI), but is there a good way to run this repeatedly for each park having a different count of points need?? It's over 300 features that I need points generated for, so an idea for a script, model builder, or batch code would be fantastic.

Ultimately each new point will have a unique identifier number.

Comment: For a starting script/model just see if you can write one that does it for a single park.  Once that works then think about how to iterate it.  If you get stuck then [edit] your question to show your code/model so far.

Comment: No need to invent bicycle, create random points tool does it, see field option

Comment: @FelixIP I think you should write a brief answer with no need for more than a link to the [tool documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm) and a copy/paste of a relevant sentence or two from it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input dataset (National Parks) has 1 row for each park boundary and it's corresponding field with number of points to create then as @FelixIP says the Create Random Points tool will do all this in one hit.

All you need to do is read the help file! Under the syntax section the fifth parameter (number_of_points_or_field) can take a field, obviously your field with the number of points you want to create.

It always pays dividends if you read the [help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm) first...

For example it's all well and good Felix and I telling you that this tool can do what you want but you did not state (*which you always should*) which license level you have as that dictates if you can actually use this tool. You'll not be surprised to find out that information is in the help file.